# AttributeError in python script using command line

Tags: python

i have written script to generate API signature from the key using (hmac-256) using python script below my code

```
import hashlib
import sys
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac


sd1=sys.argv[1]
print(sd1)
#sd='sdfhasjhas11111222sjdajsdasjdhas'
ss=''
string_to_sign = ss.encode('utf-8')
hashed = hmac.new(sd1,string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256)
print(hashed.hexdigest().upper())
```

Her **sd1** variable i need to get it as arugument and pass it to the hmac program 
am getting below error while running from command line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hmac.py", line 4, in <module>
    import hmac
  File "C:\Python27\hmac.py", line 16, in <module>
    hashed = hmac.new(sd1,string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'new'
```

This my command

```
C:\Python27>python hmac.py wewyetwyqet1212121
```

am using python 2.7 version

Comment: `hmac` has no attribute `new`. `hmac.new` doesn't exist. -- That being said the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hmac.html) do suggest it does. what happens if you do `import hmac; print dir(hmac)`?

Comment: Thanks FHTMitchell.Here i tried to run the program using IDLE this script runs fine without any issue.when i tried to include sys module and then running from command line its giving that error

Comment: I don't suppose you have any files / folders called `hmac.py` or `hmac` in your directory? That may confuse python as to which file you want to import. -- can you give us the result of what I asked? `import hmac; print dir(hmac), hmac.__file__`

Comment: ['HMAC', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_secret_backdoor_key', '_warnings', 'compare_digest', 'digest_size', 'new', 'trans_36', 'trans_5C', 'x']

Comment: And do you get the same result when you put that line at the top of your script and run it in the command line?

Comment: am getting below result       
['C:\\Python27', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "navankn.py", line 4, in <module>
    import hmac
  File "C:\Python27\hmac.py", line 16, in <module>
    digest_size = None
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'new'
Now i have changed my pthon script name into navankn.py

Comment: If you're posting code could you please format it using backticks \`code\` or edit your original question and put it there. Why is `hmac.py` in the `C:\python27` folder? It should be in `Lib`. Delete that file.

Comment: @FHTMitchell i did the same what u said now it worked thanks a lot